# How to understand equations in research papers?

Tags: career, reference-request, self-study

I was searching for latent class logit model for conjoint analysis. i found a paper which has equations for [this](http://wak2.web.rice.edu/bio/My%20Reprints/Concomitantvariablelatentclassmodels.pdf) model.

I have co-workers who knows how to decipher the meaning of these equations and write these algorithms in any language, from scratch. One of my co-worker told me that he understood what is written in this paper and can write the algorithm in R. My co-workers mostly have masters degree in engineering. I have done graduation in accounting and fortunately landed in this job of analytics. I am very keen to learn this art/science of deciphering equations in research paper.  Can anyone suggest which discipline is it or lets say any recommendation of online course or books that can help me learn this? I will be indebted for life.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could be a little more specific: which equation are you actually talking about? You mean every equation? (in this case, well it's a math course you're looking for) Only the ones with probabilities? With matrix operations?

Comment: @tlorieul i have hyperlinked this in the question text. Find below the link however. http://wak2.web.rice.edu/bio/My%20Reprints/Concomitantvariablelatentclassmodels.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have seen it but I wanted to know if you didn't understand any of these equations or if there are some that you find more difficult then others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study multiclass logistic regression; it's similar and has many tutorials. Good books include Larry Wasserman's *All of Statistics*, and [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/).

The way to understand research papers is simply to read more of them. Whenever you encounter something you don't understand follow the references or look it in one of the aforementioned books.

Answer (score 1):

Take the Machine Learning class on Coursera:

https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

It's free without a certificate.